# Tracking gas consumption by an entrypoint in smartpy during tests

Tags: smartpy, gas

I want to **check how much gas an entrypoint consumes** when we perform a transaction **when writing tests in smartpy.**

How can this be done?
Smartpy documentation too doesn't have anything that can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good solution at the moment for the tests.

I suggest you to use the explorer or the octez-client.

A future version of SmartPy may support this.